# Are reservations needed to travel in second class on Indian Railways?

Tags: trains, indian-railways

I need to travel from Chalakudy to Kozhikode. My train is Cannore express (16305). Do I need to reserve the ticket for travelling in second seating in that train?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,you have to reserve for 2nd sitting on any train in Indian Railways.

The fare for the train you have asked is Rs.80 for second sitting.

For more details see [here](https://indiarailinfo.com/train/seats/739/48/1242?kkk=1407393890914).